# Create a button that "emulate" the click of the key up or down of the keyboard (TS)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a button that when you click on it, it will do the same action as if you had clicked on the arrows up or down of the keyboard.

I've been searching around but I didn't found anything usefull.

I'm working on angular so it's typescript.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: No problem. JavaScript will do the work. may be you should go for dispatchEvent.

Comment: Just call the same function on click whatever you are calling on keyup and down , isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
pressKey(upOrDown: string) {
  if (upOrDown === 'up') {
    var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':38,'which':38});
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
  } else if (upOrDown === 'down') {
    var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':40,'which':40});
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="pressKey(variable)">clickMe</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement HostListener in your component

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

    export class Component {
    @HostListener("window:keydown", ['$event'])

      onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

        if (event.key == "ArrowUp" || event.key == "ArrowDown") {

          //call your function
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the answer for the question i think. You wrote how to wrap the ArrowUp/ArrowDown event, not a method which does the same thing

Comment: "I want to create a button that when you click on it, it will do the same action as if you had clicked on the arrows up or down of the keyboard." Basically, he can define function in his Component class, and just call this function in case it's pressed ArrowUp/ArrowDown, or call same function binding click event on that button.
I do not see why this would not be a solution.

Comment: I've understood the question as: "i need to write a function that simulate the arrowUp / arrowDown and that is called with a click on a button"

Comment: Very possible, I have understood the question in a completely different way, so there is a different solution